# Hive Map type query

Tags: hive, hbase

I have a hive table, where a column has map data type. The key is a userId and the value is a count. Is it possible to extract all the keys whose values are greater than some variable n?

This table has been externally created using hive.

Comment: Any code or foundation?

Comment: Just that one of the column has a map type. The foundation is that, The key of the map would be a userID and count is the number of times he logged in. I want to get all key whose value is greater than some number. @Evan Carslake

Answer (score 0):

You need to store you data in either a map or struct so that the key is consistent throughout the column, for example:

```
mp_col
{"userid":"user1", "count":1}
{"userid":"user2", "count":2}
{"userid":"user3", "count":3}
```

Then the query to return the rows you want is simple:

```
select mp_col["userid"] as user_ids
from table
where mp_col["count"] > 1
;
```

This will output the following table:

```
user_ids
user2
user3
```